# Definition of a lift in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Definition:** A **lift** of a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a map $\widetilde{f}: X\rightarrow \widetilde{X}$ s.t. $\rho \widetilde{f} = f$.

**Question:** What here is meant by the map $\rho$?  In my text (Hatcher) it doesn't seem to be explicitly defined.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of convering spaces ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We talk about lifting a map $f$ *through*  another map $\rho$. The map $\rho$ is therefore a part of the data, together with the spaces $X,\tilde{X}$ and the map $f$.

Comment: Need $\widetilde{X}$ and $\rho$ form a covering space for this definition to be satisfied?

Comment: Not at all, we can ask this question for any $\tilde{X}$ and $\rho$ whatsoever. However, in many naturally occurring situations, $\rho$ does have properties resembling a covering space (specifically, it is often a fibration).

Comment: So if $f: X \rightarrow  Y$, all we need to lift $f$ is another set $\widetilde{X}$, mappings $\widetilde{f}: X \rightarrow \widetilde{X}$ and $\rho: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow Y$, and the **commutative property** that $\rho \circ \widetilde{f} = f$ for us to have a lift.

Comment: Yes, then by definition, $\tilde{f}$ is a lift of $f$ through $\rho$. Of course, we rarely want just any lift, but one through a specified map $\rho$.